# Group By in stored procedure error

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created this stored procedure which is basically to return a list of offices with the type of activities that happen within each office. The results i reported to reportviewer but i noticed that for each activity return it creates a table - so i can have 5 different tables each with its own activity but all happen in the same office. I want the report to be a table for each office which will contain as many activites as there are for each office. So i thought that if i grouped in my stored procedure my results will be as what i want but i am getting column error saying: "...is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I am not sure how to go about that but here is my select, from, where, group by statements:

```
SELECT 
            O.OfficeId,
            O.OfficeName AS Office,
            HT.Description AS HearingType,
            H.HearingDate AS HearingDate,
            CR.Description AS Court,
            CT.[Description]AS CaseType
    FROM Activity H
    INNER JOIN ActivityEntry HE ON H.ActivityEntryId = HE.ActivityEntryId
    INNER JOIN ActivityType HT ON H.ActivityTypeId = HT.ActivityTypeId
    INNER JOIN [Case] C ON H.CaseId = C.CaseId
    INNER JOIN [Office] O ON HE.CreatedByOfficeId = O.OfficeId
    INNER JOIN [User] U ON C.CreatedByUserId = U.UserId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CaseType CT ON C.CaseTypeId = CT.CaseTypeId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Court CR ON C.CourtId = CR.CourtId
    WHERE .dbo.DateOnly(HE.HearingDate)BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
    GROUP  BY
            O.OfficeId,
            O.OfficeName,
            HT.Description
    ORDER BY O.OfficeId, HT.Description
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually realized that my problem cannot be solved through my stored procedure as mentioned from some of the members. Since i am displaying results in my report so i re-organized my report and dataset information so that there is a parent and child relationship and from the dataset my information was organized properly. I used the solutions offered from this post to help guide me: [post used to help guide me.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1427864.aspx/1)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using any aggregate functions (on first glance anyway) so you don't need a `group by` clause.  You can do all your ordering in the `order by` and then extract it into different datasets as you process it on the application side.

Example:

```
select ... from ... order by OfficeID, Description
```

This returns a single result for all offices.  Now you need to parse it in code

```
int OfficeID=-1;
while(recordset.moveToNextRow())
{
    if(currentRecord.OfficeID!=OfficeID)
    {
        //This is a new office, do whatever you need to do to split the data up here
        OfficeID=currentRecord.OfficeID;
    }
    //Process the record as a part of the current office here
}
```

So if you were building a table on a webpage, you'd maybe end the last table and start a new table every time you hit a new office ID.  There's some additional logic you'll need here, but this should give you the idea.

Note that your problem has nothing to do with using a stored procedure and everything to do with how you are selecting and processing data.

Comment: Thanks for informing me, for i am fairly new using stored procedures and not familiar with all its rules and uses. My main concern is that i want to order each activity according to its office. Because i am getting 5 different tables for the same office each with a different activity. i want it so that i have one table for each office with its activities listed within. Thanks...

Comment: You're going against the design of the database by trying to do this.  You want to get one dataset from the database, and from there, processes each section of it seperately.

Comment: ok i guess i have a good idea of what i need to do so will go ahead and try it and will be back. The way i have done this once before is that i actually used foreach loops in my code to organize output data but for that i wasn't using stored procedure. 
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The stored procedure doesn't change anything for you here.  Once you get the data back you'll work with it the same way you would have with a direct select, or even if you hard-coded the data into a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` requires that you have some kind of an aggregate function in your list of columns - a `SUM`, an `AVG`, a `COUNT`. `GROUP BY` only makes sense in combination with an aggregate.

Otherwise, just simply order your data with an `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: Sorry i am not very familiar with stored procedure rules, i am fairly new but thanks for informing me i will look into it right now and see what i can come up with. Thanks...